# Flex for mobile - working with databases

Tags: database, apache-flex, sqlite, mobile, flex4.5

How does working with SQLite databases work in Flex 4.5.1 for Mobile applications, please?
I'm looking to create a general class that I can reuse. For now I only want it to handle queries and return results or fault events.

Also, I am unsure if I should be using Synchronous or Asynchronous connections for mobile devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should work the same way as using SQLLite database w/ Flex 4.5.1 in non-mobile applications.

Here are some links that crop up in Google:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLConnection.html

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=SQL_03.html

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/air_sql_operations.html

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/sqlite_db_api_in_air.html

Based on a quick review of said articles; it appears they can operate in both Synchronous and aSyncrhonouse mode, depending on how you open it, using either [open](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLConnection.html#open%28%29) or [openASync](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLConnection.html#openAsync%28%29).